# DataGrid row validation base on other rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to validate a `DataGridCell` based on values of other `DataGridRows` in the same `DataGrid`. But in my inherited `MyValidationRule` object I can't access all bound items of the `DataGrid`, but only the current row.

How can I access other bound items of a DataGrid in the `Validate()` method of a `ValidationRule`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do I think is follow the visual tree up to the DataGrid and from there access the ItemsSource to perform the validation. Something like this...

```
public class SampleRowValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        BindingGroup bg = value as BindingGroup;
        if (bg != null && bg.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            DataGridRow dgrow = bg.Owner as DataGridRow;
            if(dgrow != null)
            {
                DataGrid dg = GetParent<DataGrid>(dgrow);
                // ... add more
            }
        }
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
    private T GetParent<T>(DependencyObject d) where T : class
    {
        while (d != null && !(d is T))
        {
            d = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(d);
        }
        return d as T;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a dependency property to your custom `ValidationRule` class and bind this one to the `DataGrid`.

It requires some effort though. You need to create a wrapper class that derives from `DependencyObject` and capture the `DataContext` using a `Freezable`. It is all explained in the following TechNet article. Please refer to it.

**WPF: Passing a Data Bound Value To a Validation Rule:** https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31422.wpf-passing-a-data-bound-value-to-a-validation-rule.aspx